# Can i generate a xlsx file with the Writer class?

Tags: java, xssf

Is there a way to generate a xlsx file using the `Writer` class in java?

The method i use to generate a workbook converted to a byte array:

```
private byte[] generateXlsxBytes() {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook.write(baos);
    baos.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

I try to write the bytes into the writer by doing this:

```
Writer writer = ..get the writer..
IOUtils.write(generateXlsBytes(), writer);
```

But when i try to open the file in excel i get a message saying that the markup of the file is not correct for the extension(xlsx).

I work with a custom made framework which won't allow me to use a `FileOutputStream` to write directly to a file. I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me a way to use the `Writer`.

Comment: [Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) is for writing characters and you pass a byte array to your *custom made framework* which obviously encodes the bytes to characters where you probably want to write raw bytes. As you say the framework is *custom made*, Assuming you are able to modify/extend it, I would suggest you add a method to `IOUtils` to which takes an [OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) and use that method by passing it a `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: This should work.  Are you sure you're flushing and closing the writer properly?

Comment: How can i add a method to `IOUtils`? It's part of the apache package.

Comment: Have you tried extending a class...? o.O It wasn't obvious, though, that you were using commons-io. If would get a dollar for each Java class named ioutils...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@A4L thank you for explaining it to me.

Writers are just not meant for writing raw bytes.

I just asked one of my coworkers to make a change in the framework, so that i could use an `OutputStream`